# passing a structure to a thread

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to know how to pass a structure to a thread. I've written an example application where I declare a structure in `main` and try to pass it to the thread.

Here's my code:

```
DWORD WINAPI Name1(LPVOID lparam)
{
    data x;
    x.name[15]="Sarah";
    x.DOB="19/10/2007";
    fputs(stdout,name,15);
    fputs(stdout,DOB,15);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct data
    {
        char name[15];
        char DOB[15];
    };

    HANDLE thread2;
    DWORD threadID2;
    thread2= CreateThread(NULL,0,Name1,(LPVOID *)data,0,&threadID2);

    if(thread2==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Couldn't Create Thread:("<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the hang of passing a structure to a thread :( I would really appreciate it if somebody helped me out.

I tried to change the datatype of the structure to pass it, but, I guess I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Fix the errors that prevent this from compiling first.

Comment: First, indent properly, second, explain ` I am not getting tha hang of`, third, threads share memory space. Although you are not doing anything, but still it's unsafe.

Comment: @ Jon,ok the "(LPVOID *)data" thing in the Createthread() gives me the following error: Error "error C2275: 'main::data' : illegal use of this type as an expression" 
but then I don't know how to pass a structure to a thread:(

Answer (score 6):

You are passing a local variable to the thread startup function. Once the variable goes out of scope it will be destroyed. This means it may not exist when the new thread tries to access it. You should either pass by value for integral types or allocate the object in dynamic storage (the heap).

Once the new thread has the pointer to the object it should probably be responsible for destroying it as well. That all depends on how you want to assign and manager ownership of the object.

```
struct Foo
{
    char name[15];
    char DOB[15];
};

void Start()
{
    Foo *someObject = new Foo();

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadFunc, (LPVOID *)someObject, 0, &threadID2);
}

DWORD WINAPI threadFunc(void *v)
{
    Foo *someObject = static_cast<Foo*>(v);

    delete someObject;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @MOHAMED: he can't use pthread_join on Windows threads... WaitForSingleObject() would be more appropriate here

Comment: @AaymanKhalid You can do it in `main` or in a function of your choosing. The example will work either way.

Comment: @HeisSpiter YOU ARE RIGHT I thought it's a linux pthread sorry for that

Comment: He can, ofc. But not with a thread created with CreateThread ;-)

Comment: there is one more thing,If I am writing a threaded server or client,what should I pass to the thread: socket or it's address structure?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid whichever one works best for you. If you need the information in the socket structure create a copy of it on the heap and pass a pointer to the copy. If all you need is the socket you can pass it by value (use reinterpret_cast to cast)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a struct to a thread, you've to get that struct on the heap and not on the stack and pass its address to the thread.
I also fixed a few mistakes... Like string copy, and so on...

I didn't use any typedef, as it appears you're using C++.

```
struct data{
    char name[15];
    char DOB[15];
};

DWORD WINAPI Name1(LPVOID lparam)
{
    data *x = (data*)lparam;
    strcpy(x->name, "Sarah");
    strcpy(x->DOB, "19/10/2007");
    fputs(stdout, x->name, 15);
    fputs(stdout, x->DOB, 15);

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, x);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE thread2;
    DWORD threadID2;
    data * x;

    x = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(data));
    thread2= CreateThread(NULL, 0, Name1, (LPVOID)x, 0, &threadID2);
    if(thread2==NULL)
    {
        cout << "Couldn't Create Thread:(" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `HeapAlloc` is a bit over the top. Just use `new` and `delete`.